# addSubview(...) causes additional window

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I am facing a strange behavior when loading a view controllers view with addSubview():

**Hard- and Software:**
Cocoa Swift App on OSX 10.9.5 Mavericks, XCode 6 Beta 6

**Goal:**
App, programmatically loading a ViewController from its own xib and map the VCs view on main window

**MainMenu.xib:**
Window with just one view (NSView) as anchor for the controllers view

**SpecialsVC.xib** 
View ( NSView) with just one label „Specials View“, view linked to Files owner

**Swift Code of AppDelegate and view controller SpecialsVC:**

```
class SpecialsVC : NSViewController {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) { super.init(coder: aDecoder); }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }
}


class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var anchorView: NSView!

    var specialsVC  = SpecialsVC(nibName: "SpecialsVC", bundle: nil );

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        anchorView.addSubview( specialsVC.view );    // <— 2nd window opens here
        specialsVC.view.frame = anchorView.bounds;
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {  }
}
```

**Running the app:**
1 ) Main window is opening as expected, view controller is loaded from nib, its view is placed on the anchor view of main window. —> OK
2 ) 2nd and empty window with title „Window“ opens. Can be closed, no effect to main window. —> ?????????

**Debugging:** 
The unexpected window comes up when stepping over anchorView.addSubview( specialsVC.view )

**Also tried 1:**
Load view controller not programmatically, but via outlet from View-Controller-Object in MainMenu.xib —> same effect

**Also tried 2:** 
Put a button on the main window and loaded the view controller into a local variable in the buttons action. --> no 2nd window comes up, but the controller is lost when leaving the action. Copying the local var to an instance var —> 2nd window comes up

**Hint:**
Size of 2nd window does not change when size of view controllers view is changed.

What am I doing wrong? Where comes the 2nd window from?

Kind regards Ulrich

Comment: specialsVC.xib probably contains a window, that is instantiated during specialsVC.view call. Check your xib again.

Comment: *Copying the local var to an instance var —> 2nd window comes up* I.e. the window shows up even without -[view] call? Then I must be wrong on xib idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be putting be `specialsVC.view.frame = anchorView.bounds` before your `addSubview()` method. I think that they will be ignored otherwise. It's like adding a declaration in a function after the return statement.

Comment: The order doesn't really matter.

Comment: Hi André, thanks, but the order does not matter since we are dealing with references to objects.

Comment: Hi user3125367 - you were right, I did have an unused window in my xib. How shameful.